# liveReload html with watch

Tags: html, gulp-livereload

I've got liveReload working fine with scss and js, but not with html.  here are my tasks...

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    liveReload = require('gulp-livereload');

    gulp.task('watchFiles', function () {
        liveReload.listen();
        gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss', ['compileSass']);
        gulp.watch('src/**/*.html', ['watchHtmlFiles']);
        gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['bundle-app']); 
    });
```

I needed to use run-sequence to assure my templates were built before bundling..and replaceIndex is a simple pipe for index.html over from 'src' to 'dist'

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    liveReload = require('gulp-livereload');

    gulp.task('watchHtmlFiles', function (callback) {
        runSequence('templates', 'bundle-app', 'replaceIndex', callback);
    });
```

I get an error if I include ".pipe(liveReload())" as part of the callback...so I added it to the bundle-app and replaceIndex tasks.  But this doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

this is now working, with no additional changes!  The only thing I can attribute this sudden shift is that I was running another angular project with karma running.  When that was shut down, live Reload for html files works fine....